# Get data when first application launch

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-asynctask, android-service

I'm creating a bus application, which on his first launched: parse a JSON file by URL and saves all data (lines, stations, schedules...) in a local SQLite database.

Unfortunately, writing in database takes a long time (about 2 minutes for only 6 bus lines...).
For now, I put it in a AsynTask that runs on the first application launch, and I display a ProgressBar during the execution.
But I think it is not serious to keep users waiting for 2 minutes, knowing that I will add bus lines so waiting time will increase.

So, do you have any idea of how I can handle that?

The last idea I had was to run a service to launch the application that will write data in the database, and when complete, it send a notification to user to tell him that he can use the application. At least, in the meantime, he can do what he wants and does not have to wait.
What do you think? Is there a better solution?

I take all ideas and all advice! Thank you!

Comment: Bus lines and stations rarely change. Even schedules are probably relatively static. Create the SQLite database yourself, on your developer machine, and [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to package it with your app. Update the app every month or two with a fresh database (along with bug fixes, new features, etc.). Rely on a Web service only for changes since the user last updated the app itself.

Comment: The solution is to speed up the writing. Obviously you're doing something wrong, probably you forgot to use a transaction.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the tip, I didn't know it was possible, maybe I'll do that ! But now, if it was not possible, would you choose AsynkTask + ProgressBar or Service + Notification ?
@ CL Indeed, I have not used transactions because I don't know handle nested transactions but I will retry.

Comment: "would you choose AsynkTask + ProgressBar or Service + Notification ?" -- for a two-minute operation, definitely use a `Service`. Otherwise, if the user abandons your app, your process might be terminated before you get your work done.

Comment: Ok thanks Commons!
@CL I add transactions and it works perfectly! 30 seconds instead of 3 minutes previously!
Now if I replace SQLiteDatabase.insert() by SQLiteStatement.execute(), is it worth it?

Comment: Probably not. 30 seconds is still long. How many rows are you inserting?